# Showing a Django ForeignKey value in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show a model's ForeignKey value in a template, all other fields are showing fine but I couldn't make it work. Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class BodyPart(models.Model):
    body_part = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique = True)

class Exercise(models.Model):
    body_part = models.ForeignKey(BodyPart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = "bodypart", related_name="bodypart")
```

views.py:

```
exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(category=exercisedetailcategory).values()
context = {
    "exercises" : exercises, 

}
return render(request,"exercises-categories.html",context)
```

template:

```
{% for exercise in exercises %}
<span class="post-meta-category"><a href="">{{exercise.body_part}}</a></span>
      <div class="post-item-description">
        <a href="">{{exercise.title}}</a>

        <p>{{exercise.content}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons why you should *not* use `.values()`. If you pass `Exercise` models, you can fetch the related object into memory. You can make use of `.select_related(..)` to optimize the query:

```
exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(
    category=exercisedetailcategory
).select_related('body_part')
context = {
    'exercises' : exercises, 

}
return render(request, 'exercises-categories.html', context)
```

Then in the template, we can render this with:

```
{% for exercise in exercises %}
<span class="post-meta-category"><a href="">{{ exercise.body_part.body_part }}</a></span>
      <div class="post-item-description">
        <a href="">{{ exercise.title }}</a>

        <p>{{ exercise.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can furthermore implement a `__str__` method for `BodyPart`:

```
class BodyPart(models.Model):
    body_part = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body_part
```

and then render this with:

```
{% for exercise in exercises %}
<span class="post-meta-category"><a href="">{{ exercise.body_part }}</a></span>
      <div class="post-item-description">
        <a href="">{{ exercise.title }}</a>

        <p>{{ exercise.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @EmreAylanc: you removed the `.values()` from the query?

Comment: Exactly what happens? What is displayed? What is rendered for `{{ exercise.body_part.body_part }}`?

Comment: `.select_related()` is good practice and helps creating much more efficient code. However, if performance is not an issue for you (i.e., you're just learning), you can avoid `.select_related('body_part')` from your query and you'll have access to the related object as Willem suggests `{{ exercise.body_part.body_part }}`.

Answer (score 0):

in your exercise model, ignore the default part.(its possible to show any message that tell users "no body_part" such as 
{% if not exercise.body_part %} -> No thing to show)
and make sure, you have a value in your exercise.body_part Which it means you have to have an object in your BodyPart model in relation to the current object of this model.

also it should be {{ exercise.body_part.body_part }}
the second one is to extract the value of related BodyPart objects value